# Can you store an array/list of phone numbers inside Twilio and then set key/value pairs in the 'Set Variables' widget inside of a flow?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Rather than using the SET VARIABLES widget inside of my twilio flow and manually entering in {phone1: xxx-xxx-xxxx} can I call a twilio API and set these dynamically?  I have several flows with the same SET VARIABLES widget and would prefer to update phone number in a single centralized location hosted on twilio versus going through each flow and manually adjusting that widget.

Update: It looks like it may be possible if I use the following 'parsed' syntax, {{widgets.http_GetOtherParticipants.parsed.phone1}}, but I am not sure where in Twilio I can call an API that hosts my phone numbers in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can host it as a protected [Twilio Asset](https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/overview/services).

[Twilio Functions UI](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions)